# Is there a way to find out the class of form using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, awt

I am working on a large undocumented application written in swing/awt.  I have to make changes to it and i need to find out what class a form belongs to when i open it. Is there a way to do this via eclipse?

For example: I open the application and to do something with the app such that some frame opens.  How do i find out the class of that form? Can this be done through eclipse?

I know i can comb trough the logic but this is a very laborious and largely ineffective process, chunks of the logic are either in jar files or obfuscated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For figuring out how a given Swing frame is put together, I have found Swing Explorer to be *VERY* helpful.

https://swingexplorer.dev.java.net/

After installing the Eclipse plugin, note that you need to "Run as ->" to invoke Swing Explorer properly.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is what you need, but maybe you should try searching(MainMenu-->Search) your entire Project for the specific Window title (String) that comes up with this particular window.

Comment: lolz, that's the first thing i did but it didnt help me, in the meantime i found this hackish program called  WinID (google it) that tells you what class it is when you mouse over the form.  i am still looking for a more elegant way though.